# Matplotlib Animation : Graph can't appear

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Recently I have managed to do the animation. But now I can't make the tangent line went as I want (not even displayed yet). The formula of the tangent line is y=(2/r)(sqrt(1-((r^2)/4))-1)x +r. The formula is obtained from 2 circles equation (C1 and C2). C1(blue) : x^2+y^2=r^2, and C2(green) : (x-1)^2+y^2=1. My goal is to obtain this kind of animation as [image: reference] and my current animation goes like this [image: now].

How should the code looks like when the animation looks like the reference one (the first one)? Any comments and answers would be very helpful for me as a beginner, I appreciate it, Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
line2, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax.set_xlim(-5,5)
ax.set_ylim(-5,5)
# theta goes from 0 to 2pi
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

# the radius of the circle
r = np.sqrt(1)
r2 = np.sqrt(4)

# compute x1 and x2
x1 = 1+r*np.cos(theta)
y1 = r*np.sin(theta)
x2 = r2*np.cos(theta)
y2 = r2*np.sin(theta)

# Move left y-axis and bottim x-axis to centre, passing through (0,0)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

# Eliminate upper and right axes
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

# Show ticks in the left and lower axes only
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
def init2():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line2,
def animate(i):
    x2 = np.sqrt(i)*np.cos(theta)
    y2 = np.sqrt(i)*np.sin(theta)
    line.set_data(x2, y2)
    return line,
def animate2(i):
    x3 = np.linspace(0,r2**2,100)
    y3 = ((2/r2)*(np.sqrt(1-(r2**2)/4)-1)*x3)+r2
    line.set_data(x3, y3)
    return line,

# create the figure
ax.plot(x1,y1)
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.grid()
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                interval=1000, blit=False,\
                                frames=np.hstack([range(0), 
                                                  range(4)[::-1]]))
anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, init_func=init2,
                                interval=1000, blit=False)
                                
plt.show()

f = r"D:/UNPAR/Semester 2/Pemrograman Komputer/Project/SK.gif" 
writergif = animation.PillowWriter(fps=30) 
anim.save(f, writer=writergif)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation functions need to be combined into one. We will combine them into an initialization function and an animation function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2, color='green')
line2, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2, color='red')
ax.set_xlim(-5,5)
ax.set_ylim(-5,5)

# theta goes from 0 to 2pi
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

# the radius of the circle
r = np.sqrt(1)
r2 = np.sqrt(4)

# compute x1 and x2
x1 = 1+r*np.cos(theta)
y1 = r*np.sin(theta)
x2 = r2*np.cos(theta)
y2 = r2*np.sin(theta)

# create the figure
ax.plot(x1,y1)
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.grid()

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    return line,line2

def animate(i):
    x2 = np.sqrt(i)*np.cos(theta)
    y2 = np.sqrt(i)*np.sin(theta)
    print(max(y2))
    line.set_data(x2, y2)

    x3 = [0, 4-(0.1*i)]
    y3 = [max(y2), 0]
    line2.set_data(x3, y3)    
    return line,line2


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1000, blit=False,frames=np.arange(10,0,-1))
                 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: Let me repeat that. Please use the check mark below the VOTE to accept the answer.